# Low battery notifications on Windows Mobile 5.0

Tags: power-management, windows-mobile

I have a `Fujitsu-Siemens Pocket LOOX 560` with `Windows Mobile 5.0` installed.

When the power is low, it gives the low power notifications even when the device is turned off. The notifications turn the devices on, which lights the screen, plays the sound, turns `Bluetooth` and `Wi-Fi` on etc., in other words does everything to drain the battery which is already low.

Is it possible to disable low power notifications when the device is off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to Today-Settings-Personal-Sound & Notification.
Select Notification tab, choose Low Battery from drop-down list, you can disable sound and/or warning message.

If the low battery warning option does not appear in the drop down list, you will need to edit the following registry entry first;

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\Notifications{A877 D663-239C-47a7-9304-0D347F580408}\

Open the String value with the name "Default" and add the value "Low Batt Warning".

Comment: It will disable the warning when the device is on as well, won't it?

Comment: Unforunatly yes it will, unless someone can make an app to tweak it

Comment: This answers my question (it *does* disable notifications when the device is off). This does disable them when it's on too, but I think I can learn to live with it.